# Nested Select in Hive

Tags: hive

Can I have nested `select`with different conditions in Hive? e.g.

If I have the following two Hive queries:

```
select percentile(x, 0.95)
from t1
where y = 1;

select percentile(x, 0.95)
from t1
where y = 2;
```

Can I select the two percentiles above in one query – something like (it doesn't work):

```
select
  (select percentile(x, 0.95)
    from t1
    where y = 1),
  (select percentile(x, 0.95)
    from t1
    where y = 2)
from t1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using `UNION ALL`, for example:

```
select * from
  (select percentile(x, 0.95)
    from t1
    where y = 1
   union all
   select percentile(x, 0.95)
    from t1
    where y = 2) x;
```

Comment: Edited to fix a minor syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to avoid multiple scans of the table, if it is very large.

```
select percentile( if( y = 1 , x, 0 ), 0.95 ) as percentile_1
       percentile( if( y = 2 , x, 0 ), 0.95 ) as percentile_2
from t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also try:

```
select percentile( case when y=1 then x else null end, 0.95) as p95_1
     , percentile( case when y=2 then x else null end, 0.95) as p95_2
from table;
```

The percentile() will ignore null values.